# MySQL frequent queries and persistent connections

Tags: mysql

I am going to be hosting a gaming website for a bunch of card games that are pretty popular in my country. Since there is really no other convenient way to do this apart from web sockets I decided that's the path I'm going to take. Anyhow there are a bunch of concerns that I have.

I plan on having multiple servers for each type of game and each server is going to host for about 100-200 people. With that being said it is necessary for players to see information about the server before joining, such as how many players are connected, what is the average wait time and such. To do this I could either use files or a database. I would very much like to go with the database but I'd like to ask a few questions about MySQL

- I know that MySQL was not built for real-time applications but  what is an acceptable interval for each server to update its status in the database?
- Are there any problems I may run into when having persistent connections from each server to the MySQL server?
- Are there any benefits to preparing the statement that is going to update the database and then execute it every N seconds or I should prepare it each time? I am asking this because I don't know what happens when a statement is prepared so having a prepared statement in a persistent connection may not be a good idea.
- Using InnoDB, is there any need to create a separate MySQL server solely for this purpose or I could use the server that is used for the site. Not really sure if those updates every N seconds would affect anything.

Comment: Have a look at CouchDB and PouchDB.

Comment: @Joerg I just did, but those are local databases, I don't see how this helps.

Comment: @ Emilio: You can use CouchDB as a remote database, there are providers which offer it. PouchDB is the local version of it.

Comment: @Joerg Thanks for the suggestion and correction. Maybe if MySQL turns out to be impossibly inconvenient I would consider CouchDB